# grid search - optimal weighting of classifiers

Tags: grid-search, ensemble

I am using three different of the shelf classifiers. It's a three class classification task.
I want to calculate the [optimal weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777181/how-to-tune-weights-in-voting-classifier-sklearn) (c1weight, c2weight, c3weight) for each classifier (real task more classifiers and also weights for each class).

Maybe simple grid search approach or [sklearn ensemble classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) could do that.

```
vc = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('gbc',GradientBoostingClassifier()),
                   ('rf',RandomForestClassifier()),('svc',SVC(probability=True))],
                   voting='soft',n_jobs=-1)

params = {'weights':[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]]}
grid_Search = GridSearchCV(param_grid = params, estimator=vc)
grid_Search.fit(X_new,y)
print(grid_Search.best_Score_)
```

I don't understand how to implement this for the following code.

```
def get_classification(text, c1weight, c2weight, c3weight):

  prediction1 = classifier1.predict(text)
  if prediction1 = 1:
    class1 =+ 1 * c1weight
  elif prediction1 = 2:
    class2 =+ 1  * c1weight
  else:
    class3 =+ 1  * c1weight


  prediction2 = classifier2.predict(text)
  if prediction2 = 1:
    class1 =+ 1 * c2weight
  elif prediction2 = 2:
    class2 =+ 1  * c2weight
  else:
    class3 =+ 1  * c2weight


  prediction3 = classifier3.predict(text)
  if prediction3 = 1:
    class1 =+ 1 * c3weight
  elif prediction3 = 2:
    class2 =+ 1  * c3weight
  else:
    class3 =+ 1  * c3weight


  if class1 > class2 and class1 > class3:
    return ("class1",class1)
  elif class2 > class1 and class2 > class3:
    return ("class2",class2)
  else:
    return("class3",class3)

c1weight = 0.5
c2weight = 0.7
c3weight = 0.4

for i, row in df_raw.iterrows():
    classification = get_classification(df_raw.at[i, 'text'],c1weight, c2weight, c3weight)
    df_raw[i,'classification'] = classification 
  
score = get_accuracy(df_raw['classification'],df_raw['label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

GridSearch finds those optimals weights for you.

You can access these weights through the attribute *best_params_* of the GridSearch object, which will return all the optimal parameters (including the weights):

```
optimal_weights = grid_Search.best_params_
```

Comment: in that case my function must return the desired accuracy measure?

Comment: Yes, because because GridSearchCV uses ParameterGrid in the background but will return you the scores (cross validated) and best parameters : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV

Comment: Please don't write the answer in your original post,  post it below (and I think you want to use GridSearchCV instead of a simple ParameterGrid)

Answer (score 0):

*(This is the asker's solution, moved from question and comment to answer)*

---

[This sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370570/elegant-grid-search-in-python-numpy) helped me to understand it:

```
def your_function(number):
    print(number)

from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
param_grid = {'param1': [1, 2, 3]}

grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)

for params in grid:
    your_function(params['param1'])
```

I had too much paramaters for gridsearch. In this case it would take months to calculate all combinations. Finally i used hyperopt for the hyperparameter optimization. There are some nice basic tutorials out there. This one helped me a lot. You can also find a python notebook there. https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introductory-example-of-bayesian-optimization-in-python-with-hyperopt-aae40fff4ff0